# Facebook Friends List which aren't on the app in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how can I get a complete friends list with users ids on FB iOS SDK?

"/me/friends" just shows me the user's friends who are already on the app & "/me/taggable_friends" gives me this list but with encrypted ids. I'm trying to implement something like this Down to Lunch feature: a box to invite your friends to use the app.

Thanks!

[Down to Lunch feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFMo3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How to invite friends to an App is explained in the FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq

(See "How can people invite their friends to use my app?")